# How to execute a undefined number of funcA() and funcB() before starting funcC()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a app writed in javascript.
To work, I need to download a bunch of files.
Since I can have a lot of file wich can be long, I made the download asynchronous:

```
function download_all(xml, callback){
    var i=0;
    while(i<xml.smil.length)
    {
        download(xml.smil[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<xml.video.length)
    {
        download(xml.video[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
    callback(xml);
}
```

My question is: download do have a callback, but since there can be 5 smil and 30 videos, how can I make sure all of the download will be made before the callback of download_all is called?

I thougth of incrementing a variable after each complete download (in the callback) and something like

```
while(smildlcompleted<xml.smil.length && videodlcompleted<xml.video.length)
{
    sleep(1000);
}
```

Like I would have do in C, but I can t find a sleep function and it seems to be opposite to the rigth syntax of js/node.js.

Is there a way to wait for all download to complete before the callback?

I did have a look at [How to execute a Javascript function only after multiple other functions have completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278018/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-only-after-multiple-other-functions-have-co), since the problem is quite the same (funcA(), funcB(), and when all done, funcC()), but in my case, funcA() and funcB() can be launched ten or twenty times before I need to do funcC().

I m trying to modify the answer code of the other question to do what I need, but does someone know any easier way?

Comment: do you want the downloads to be in parallel or series?

Comment: Since there s a lot of download, I tought parallel is better, but I must be sure the callback is send after all download are completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the **[Async Github](https://github.com/caolan/async)** library. It can be used in both node js and browser.
You either need `async.parallel` or `async.series`.

Comment: It seems async.series is what I m looking for, if I find how to use it correctly

Comment: But its looks like you need async.parallel

Comment: Revisiting my olds question. `async` is a really good tool that I since used extensively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
function download_all(xml, callback){
    var i=0 , no_of_downloads , downloadsCompleted;
    no_of_downloads = xml.smil.length + xml.video.length;

    downloadsCompleted = 0;

    function afterDownload(){
        downloadsCompleted + =1;
        if(downloadsCompleted ===no_of_downloads ) { // all downloads are completed
            callback();    //call the callback here
        } 
    }

    while(i<xml.smil.length)
    {
       download(xml.smil[i],afterDownload);
       i=i+1;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<xml.video.length)
    {
      download(xml.video[i],afterDownload);
      i=i+1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Had to tweak some part of my code, but this function work perfectly