# jquery custom validation method with a callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So I just found that you can add any custom validation logic. If it's simple enough it's not a problem, right?

```
$.validator.addMethod('customRule',function(val, el){
    return val > 2;
},'value cannot be smaller than 2');

$('#myInput').rules('add', { customRule : true });
```

now, even if you have something a little bit more difficult (a REST call for example) it still can be done:

```
$.validator.addMethod('customRule',function(val, el){
    var validator = this;
    $.get('checkValueOnServer',val).done(function(isValid){
        if(!isValid){
           var errors = {}; 
           errors[el.name] = 'server says: value does not look right!';
           validator.showErrors(errors);
        }
        validator.stopRequest(el, isValid);
    })
    return 'pending';
},'');
```

now, in my case I need to call a function with a callback, something like that

```
$.validator.addMethod('customRule',function(val, el){
    var validator = this;
    checkValueOnServer(el, function(isValid){ // so function runs for a few secs and returns a callback with a result 
        if(!isValid){
           var errors = {}; 
           errors[el.name] = 'called function says: value does not look right!';
           validator.showErrors(errors);
        }
        validator.stopRequest(el, isValid);
    });
    return 'pending';
},'');
```

You see just a good old callback, not `deferred` object. So in the later case if I call

`$('form').valid()` it reports it's true, although custom called function reports that the validation rule didn't pass and the element is highlighted and error message is shown. So what's wrong? What's the right way to tell that thing: the form is invalid?

Comment: Please construct a jsFiddle demo of this issue.  I almost cannot believe that `.valid()` is returning `true` while there are invalid fields - that's not supposed to happen.  Clearly, either something is wrong with your code or the plugin... probably not the plugin.

Comment: I guess I can try workaround by storing last time check timestamp and value. Here's what I'm talking about (only value yet without the timestamp) http://plnkr.co/edit/eK6OGZ4qto4wqOsBoXBH. I guess I have to decide now what would be minimal timespan within which the value will be assumed correct. Without needing to check again...

Answer (score 3):

When using a custom validation method, the function typically only returns a `true` or a `false`.

- If your custom validation function returns `true`, the element passed validation and there is no error message triggered.  http://jsfiddle.net/kCqy5/1/
- If your custom validation function returns `false`, the element failed validation and an error message is displayed.  http://jsfiddle.net/kCqy5/2/
- If your custom validation function does not return `true` or `false`, then the results do not seem to be very predictable.  http://jsfiddle.net/kCqy5/

Yours is only returning a string that contains the text `'pending'`, the `required` error message is displayed even though the form passes validation.  Your usage is outside the scope of the documentation...

---

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage):

> **method**  Callback
>  The actual method implementation, **returning true if an element is valid**. First argument: Current value. Second argument: Validated element. Third argument: Parameters.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277901/fixing-a-delayed-callback-causing-false-errors-in-jquery-validation-w-jquery-mo

Comment: @Agzam, I'm not sure what you're showing me because it proves my point.  Examining the code in [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277901/fixing-a-delayed-callback-causing-false-errors-in-jquery-validation-w-jquery-mo), you can see that the variable called `nameUnique` will contain `true` when it needs to pass validation.

Comment: again, for my case just a simple function that returns false or true not sufficient, I need something that returns a callback and depending on that callback sets the properties to be valid or not

Comment: @Agzam, and again, this method only understands `true` or not `true` with regards to a custom rule created with `addMethod`.  So what I'm telling you is that returning the string containing `'pending'` is no different than returning `false`... this custom rule will never be satisfied.

Comment: @Agzam, you're going to have to explain yourself better than that.  My answer is quoting directly from the documentation.

Comment: well, that's one undocumented feature... let's you have 'delayed' validation

Comment: @Agzam, if you believe this is an undocumented feature, then you should report it to [the jQuery Validate Github site](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) as buggy or broken.  In this most basic example, it's behaving just like in your complaint.  Passing validation while the error message still appears.  http://jsfiddle.net/kCqy5/

Comment: actually I just figured it out... it's not a bug... It's my own fault. Sorry, sorry. I apologize and appreciate your help. The problem was in the callback function. I had to return the element back. It's kinda really difficult to explain without showing the code itself. right now it just has a lot of irrelevant stuff. Maybe sometime later I'll try to separate my custom validation logic and put it on github.